# building rosjava_core

Tags: ros, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to reinstall rosjava_core from source.
I uninstalled debian rosjava_core, and downloaded the newest version from source `hg clone https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/ rosjava_core`.
Then I tried to follow [this](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html) tutorial (There seems to be an update for the rosjava_core on 31.March. the following two steps are deleted

```
./gradlew rosjava_bootstrap:install
rosrun rosjava_bootstrap install_generated_modules.py rosjava
```

). but as I run `./gradlew install` the follwing failure occured.
it was no problem when I first installed rosjava from debian...
I noticed this is a problem when installing docs. I don't actually need them. can I skip this step?

```
...
> Building > :docs:javadoc > Resolving dependencies ':rosjava_tutorial_pubsub:co:docs:javadoc
/home/evelyn/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc_server/src/main/java/org/apache/xmlrpc/webserver/WebServer.java:72: warning - Tag @link: reference not found: ServletWebServer
1 warning
:docs:install
sphinx-build -b html -d build/doctrees   src/main/sphinx build/html
Running Sphinx v1.0.1
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [html]: targets for 5 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 5 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 20%] best_practices
reading sources... [ 40%] building
reading sources... [ 60%] getting_started
reading sources... [ 80%] index
reading sources... [100%] overview

looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [ 20%] best_practices
writing output... [ 40%] building
writing output... [ 60%] getting_started

Exception occurred:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygments/lexers/__init__.py", line 80, in get_lexer_by_name
    raise ClassNotFound('no lexer for alias %r found' % _alias)
ClassNotFound: no lexer for alias u'groovy' found
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-nCDX3T.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
Either send bugs to the mailing list at <http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/>,
or report them in the tracker at <http://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issues/>. Thanks!
make: *** [html] Error 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':docs:install'.
> Command 'make' finished with (non-zero) exit value 2.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 19.881 secs
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31070/building-rosjava_core/) by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had the same issue, inside your rosjava_core directory, there should be a file called settings.gradle. Open it up with your favorite editor, and after the comment header there is a line that says include 'rosjava_bootstrap' etc etc. The last one is 'docs', simply comment out that part and the install worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [Jyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2115/jyo/) with karma: 100 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have an outdated version of pygments installed. You can either do as Jyo suggested or call ./gradlew install -x docs:install to exclude building the documentation.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-04-04**:
As a note, it looks like syntax highlighting for Groovy (the language backbone that Gradle uses) was added to pygments in version 1.5 (http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/)